# Sending multiple data parameters with single quote with jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am using ajax jquery method to pass value to server, but my problem is i am using some value with `single quote` `'` and it's give me error ,

ClientManager = "Client's Manager " **<== here i am passing value with ' (single quote)**

---

```
  data: "{projectSoid': '" + ProjectId + "','startDate': '" + StartDate + "','endDate': '" + EndDate + "','clientManager': '" + ClientManager + "'}",
```

and ajax jquery method, Error give me error :-

**Message: Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. ........**

infect i want all fields allows with ' (single quote)

what's the best soulution to passdata as jQuery Ajax Methods's `data : {`

Comment: try escaping, like, "Client\'s Manager"

Comment: huh! is it solution? Dear , i am not expecting that end user type client name as  : Client\'s Manager"

Comment: Who the hell said that end user types that in. Bye, dear

Comment: you can use encodeURIComponent to encode this single quote.

Comment: data: {projectSoid: ProjectId ,startDate:  StartDate ,endDate: EndDate ,clientManager: ClientManager}

Comment: Message: Invalid JSON primitive: projectSoid!

Answer (score 2):

Try defining an object literal, instead of concatenating a String.

```
data: {
        "projectSoid": ProjectId,
        "startDate": StartDate,
        "endDate": EndDate,
        "clientManager": ClientManager
      },
          //other entries
```

Comment: If he want it as a string JSON.stringify({...})

Comment: @ArunPJohny That would also work, but with the object literal you avoid all of the concatenation.

Comment: give me error like : Message: Invalid JSON primitive: projectSoid

Comment: @NestorC could you post the full jquery Ajax code? I may be wrong, I'm assuming your using .Net after some research, I was posting this answer from a java perspective.  http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistake-invalid-json-primitive/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293717/message-invalid-json-primitive-ajax-jquery-method-with-c-sharp-webmethod