# Message: Invalid JSON primitive: ajax jquery method with Webmethod

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using Data value as object literal, instead of concatenating a String as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293091/sending-multiple-data-parameters-with-single-quote-with-jquery-ajax/15293209?noredirect=1#comment21581381_15293209)

My code is the following:

```
$.ajax({    
  url: "../Member/Home.aspx/SaveClient",
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: {
    "projectSoid": ProjectId,
    "startDate": StartDate,
    "endDate": EndDate,
    "clientManager": ClientManager
  },
  success: function(response) {
    if (response.d != "") {

    }
  },
  error: function(response) {
    var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
    alert("Message: " + r.Message);
    alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
    alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
  }
})
```

and my webmethod is like this :

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveClient(string projectSoid, string startDate, 
     string endDate, string clientManager)
{
    ...
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Message: Invalid JSON primitive: projectSoid

Comment: You need to JSON.strigify your data: `data: JSON.strigify({
                        "projectSoid": ProjectId,
                        "startDate": StartDate,
                        "endDate": EndDate,
                        "clientManager": ClientManager
                    }),`

Comment: Any comment on my comment? Have you tried it? Does it worked?

Comment: i do not know what is JSON.strigify? i got error that it is not function :(

Comment: Which browser are you using? You may need the [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) in older browsers

Comment: please replay as answer, so i can select it

Comment: +1 nemesv. Solved my issue :)

Comment: Nestor got a error because nemesv typo error (missed a **n**): JSON.stringify

Comment: @nemesv The correct spelling is JSON.stringify

Answer (score 40):

With your `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` you are claiming that you will send JSON but currently your `data` property is not holding JSON.

You need to transform your `data` to JSON with the `JSON.stringify` method:

So change your `data` property to:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    "projectSoid": ProjectId,
    "startDate": StartDate,
    "endDate": EndDate,
    "clientManager": ClientManager
}),
```

You should note that the `JSON.stringify` method is not natively supported in older browsers so you may need to provide an implementation with using one of the various libraries like:

Douglas Crockford's [JSON2 library.](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

Comment: @nemesv: Thanks Nemev:Just one correction in your code... U wrongly spelled stringify as strigify...

Comment: @NestorC : can you accept this as answer if it meets your needs? So that it will help to somebody...

Comment: If you don't want to use JSON.stringify, you can remove the content type. By default, content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). I prefer to use JSON.stringify just like @nemesv pointed out but I just wanted to say that it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript at Client side**

```
 var items = [{ projectSoid: ProjectId, startDate: StartDate, endDate: EndDate, clientManager: ClientManager }];


                   $.ajax({
                       url: '"../Member/Home.aspx/SaveClient',
                       type: "POST",
                       data: JSON.stringify({ items: items }),

                       //data:  JSON.stringify("{DocKey : '" + DocKey + "',highlightText: '" +  JSON.stringify(text) + "',pageNo: '" + pgNo + "',left: '" + left + "',top: '" + top + "',width: '" + width + "',height: '" + height + "'}"),

                       //data: "{DocKey\":\""+ DocKey+"\",\"highlightText\":\""+ text +"\",\"pageNo\":\""+pgNo+"\",\"left\":\""+left+"\",\"top\":\""+top+",\"width\":\""+width+"\",\"height\":\""+ height +"}}",
                       // data: "{DocKey : '" + DocKey + "',highlightText: '" + text + "',pageNo: '" + pgNo + "',left: '" + left + "',top: '" + top + "',width: '" + width + "',height: '" + height + "'}",
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       dataType: "json",
                       beforeSend: function () {
                           alert("Start!!! ");
                       },
                       success: function (data) {
                           alert("Save data Successfully");
                       },
                       failure: function (msg) { alert("Sorry!!! "); evt.obj.deleteObject(); },
                       async: false

                   });
```

**Web Method at Code behind**

```
[WebMethod]       
 public static string SaveClient(object items)       {

    List<object> lstItems = new     JavaScriptSerializer().ConvertToType<List<object>>(items);

  Dictionary<string, object> dic = (Dictionary<string, object>)lstItems[0];

    }
```